# Show / Hide Form Elements based on Select

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to Show / Hide two elements based on a selection - a label and an input using Javascript getElementsByName.  It works with getElementByID if I change things around on the label and input but for some reason Name isn't working.  Here is the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function Toggle(obj){
 var val=obj.value;
 if (!obj.m){ obj.m=''; }
 if (!obj.m.match(val)){ obj.m+=','+val+','; }
 var hide=obj.m.split(',');
 for (var zxc0=0;zxc0<hide.length;zxc0++){
  if (document.getElementsByName(hide[zxc0])){
   document.getElementsByName(hide[zxc0]).style.display='none';
  }
 }
 var show=val.split(',');
 for (var zxc1=0;zxc1<show.length;zxc1++){
  if (document.getElementsByName(show[zxc1])){
   document.getElementsByName(show[zxc1]).style.display='';
  }
 }
}

//-->
</script>
```

and here are for form elements:

```
            <div id="styled-select">
            <select name="how" onchange="Toggle(this);" class="dropdown">
                    <option value="Internet Search">Internet Search</option>
                    <option value="Facebook" >Facebook</option>
                    <option value="Twitter" >Twitter</option>
                    <option value="LinkedIN" >LinkedIN</option>
                    <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            </div>                
            <label name="Referral" style="display:none;">Referred By:</label>
            <input name="Referral" style="display:none;" value="" class="hidden-txt">
```

When the user selects "Referal" it should display the Label and Input named "Referral".  I had this working if I used getElementByID, gave the option two values separated by comma and used seperate IDs for the label and input.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns an array not an element.

Comment: Is there something else you would recommend other than "ID", since I need to show two form elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName(hide[zxc0]);
if(elems) {
    for(var i = 0;i < elems.length;i++) {
       elems[i].style.display='none';
       //Do whatever else you need to do with the element.
    }
}
```

As mentioned by Kevin Boucher, getElementsByName returns an array. Assuming that you want to apply the display=none style to all elements with that name, the code above will achieve that. Also for performance's sake, the above code only calls document.getElementsByName() once as opposed to the 3+ times above which I'm sure will be beneficial.

It might be worth investigating [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for its ease of selecting elements.